# The node.js client request header is being displayed as host: 127.0.0.1 , connection : 'Close'

Tags: node.js

I have to print from the server the request header sent by the client.

```js
var qs = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');
const { request } = require('https');
// create server with anonymous callback function
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    var options = {
        method: 'HEAD',
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: '40012'
    };

    //here is where the server should display the clients request header
    var clientHeader = request.headers;
    console.log(request.headers);

}).listen(40012, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running http://127.0.0.1:40012');
console.log('Process ID:', process.pid);
```

> The server is printing only: { host: '127.0.0.1:40012', connection: 'close' }

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add more details about the version of the node as well?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried executing your code locally. and I got the following response. on hitting the URL http://127.0.0.1:40012

```
Server running http://127.0.0.1:40012
Process ID: 52240
{
  host: 'localhost:40012',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,gu;q=0.7,ar;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.5',
  cookie: 'token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7Il9pZCI6IjYxNzEzYzVmOWYzYjAzZWIyMmQ0NmYzNSIsImVtYWlsIjoicmFqZW5kcmEyMDc5MUBnbWFpbC5jb20ifSwiaWF0IjoxNjM0ODQzMzI4fQ.CgQWS5dImbFCNnvBpbtAuWyjpScRSTYxvZvhDmHQ0Lw'
}
```

However, the code is incomplete so the request from the browser will be stuck. the complete code can be as follows. We need to give a response to the client.

```js
var http = require('http');
// create server with anonymous callback function
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  //here is where the server should display the clients request header
  console.log(request.headers);
  // This is response body.
  response.write('This is response');
  // This will mark the end of the response.
  response.end();

}).listen(40012, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running http://127.0.0.1:40012');
console.log('Process ID:', process.pid);
```

Comment: I implement the code you provided, however, still the same.

Would be something configured wrongly in the client?

Comment: const { Console } = require('console');
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');
var options = {
method: 'HEAD',
host: '127.0.0.1',
port: '40012'
};
http.request(options, function(response){
var qrytoparse =qs.stringify(response.headers);
console.log(qrytoparse);
var parsedqry = qs.parse(qrytoparse,"%");
console.log(parsedqry);
}).end();

Comment: Can you provide more details about what exactly are you trying to achieve with this code?